# antd select clear value

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this select component that displays a list of elements to select in the div below according to the onChange:

```
<Select
  showSearch
  placeholder={translate('start_typing')}
  allowClear
  onChange={handleOnSelect}
  onSearch={handleSearch}
  defaultValue={selectedIcon.name}
  open={false}
>
  {solidIconList.map(({name}) => (
    <Option key={name} value={name}>
      <span className="icon-picker__text">{name}</span>
    </Option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

I have set open to false so the dropdown does not appear,  the problem is that when I select an element and after start typing again on the searchbar, the previous value selected does not get removed, any idea what can be the issue here?.

issue :
[image]

Comment: Please, provide reproducible environment link.

Comment: Hi Filip thanks for your reply, finally what I did is to change the select by an input, it solved the issue for me,